# How do I install WSO2 API Manager on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, wso2, wso2-api-manager

```
[mgallardo@app ~]$ helm install admin-apis wso2/am-pattern-1 --version 4.0.0-1 --namespace infraesctrutura --set wso2.subscription.username=admin --set wso2.subscription.password=admin

Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: unable to parse the server version: invalid character 'C' looking for beginning of value
```

```
API Manager Publisher: https://am.wso2.com/publisher
API Manager DevPortal: https://am.wso2.com/devportal
API Manager Carbon Console: https://am.wso2.com/carbon
```